# Remove particular row by clicking remove link present in the same row

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have form 1st page(test.php) as follows

```html
<form method="post" action="newtest.php">
  <input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(in_array("1", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  alt="1607.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="2" <?php if(in_array("2", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="1848.00" /> 
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="3" <?php if(in_array("3", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="180.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="4" <?php if(in_array("4", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="650.00" />
  <input name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="5" <?php if(in_array("5", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> alt="495.00" />
     <div class="ph-float">
         <input type="submit" name="button" value="Checkout >>" class="ph-button ph-btn-green fm-submit" disabled="true" >
     </div> 
</form>
```

Based on checkbox selection am displaying Book name,Amount and total in a table as follows(newtest.php)
(Remember am not using data base, these values are not comming from data base instad am taking these values from
product array as specified below)

```html
<?php     
 $product = array();
 $product[1] = array('name' => "Text Book of Human Anatomy by B.D.Chaurasiavol 6th edition Vol -I Vol-II Vol-III.", 'price' => 1607);
 $product[2] = array('name' => "Nettars Atlas of Anatomy", 'price' => 1848);
 $product[3] = array('name' => "Genera Anatomy by B.D.Chaurasia", 'price' => 180);
 $product[4] = array('name' => "Inderbir Singh Embryology 10th edition ", 'price' => 650);
 $product[5] = array('name' => "Inderbir Singh Histology ", 'price' => 495);
               
        if(isset($_POST['button']))
 {   
        $first = array();
    $second = array();
     foreach ($_POST['product'] as $pId)
      {
  $first[] = $product[$pId]['name'];
  $second[] = $product[$pId]['price']; 
      }
   $bookauthor = count($first);
   $bookprice = count($second);
   $max = ($bookauthor > $bookprice ? $bookauthor : $bookprice);
   echo '<br />';
   echo '<i style="font-color:#000000;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;font-size:21px; padding-left:110px;margin-top:10px"> List of books you have selected:</i>';
   echo '<table>';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th style="text-align: center">SL No.</th>';
   echo "<th>Book Name</th>";
   echo "<th>Amount in INR</th>";
          echo "<th>Action</th>";
   echo '</tr>';
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
     {
  $count++;
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td style='text-align: center'>{$count}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$first[$i]}</td>";
  echo "<td>{$second[$i]}</td>";
                echo "<td><a href='#'><i style='color:#F5F5F5;background:#D52020'>REMOVE</i> </a></td>";
  echo '</tr>';
     }
  $total =  array_sum($second);
  echo '<tr>';
  echo "<td colspan='2' style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14px'>Total Amount</td>";
  echo "<td style='font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;'>{$total}</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo '</table>';
        }
?>
```

I want to remove particular row from table when i click on REMOVE link displaying in a same row, how to achive this? 
link is ok or should i have to use button.If any one write some code may helpfull as am new webie... 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the row in the current table, or also from the php?

Comment: just call you php to remove record and pass record primary key.

Comment: @Sean i want to remove the row from table and calculate remaining fields like total amount based on remaining rows. --Update--- I want to remove it from php

Comment: @ Manoj Actually am not using data base in this point , these values are not fetching from data base instad am getting these values from 2nd page newtest.php based on posted checkbox values from test.php,Any help may appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
$('i').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('a').parent('td').parent('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: since the `<i>` is inside a `<a>` you may want to do `$('i').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...` to prevent the default link action.

Comment: thank you sir, its working awesome to remove particular row , but the  total value is not calculating based on remaining rows and count value also not decreasing based on removal(if i remove 2nd row sl.no of first row is 1 itself that is ok but 3rd row is 3 no changes, 3rd row sl.no supposed to be changed to 2 ) can you please update the code it may helpfull

Comment: @Nag Then you should use AJAX to achieve this. Once the row is removed than remove it from database also and select again and load it your browser. Hope you are familiar with AJAX/jQuery, if not than you can feel free to mail me on vipulhadiya@ymail.com. I will guide you.

Comment: Actually am not using data base in this point , these values are not fetching from data base instad, am getting these values from 2nd page newtest.php based on posted checkbox values from test.php,

Answer (score 0):

The row is deleted but as clicking makes you follow the link, it's immediately restored when the page is refreshed.

Add return false; or event.preventDefault(); at the end of the callback to prevent the default behavior :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#favoriteFoodTable .deleteLink").on("click",function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
        tr.remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Thank you sir,Can you please update your script with my code , because am not getting where i need to put this script and what are  the changes i need to do in my code